# How to add new route/PREDICATE to spring cloud gateway version 4.0.6

Tags: java, spring, microservices, spring-cloud-gateway, application.properties

This is my application.properties in my gateway microservice:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=regs-auth
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://regs-auth-ms
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/v1/auth/register
```

The whole project can be found on: https://github.com/VictorFerreiraS/LoginSystemBackEnd

Any tip on how to get more information on spring boot cloud gateway would be lovely (despite the documentation obviously ;) )

I tried this but I only got 404's in postman!

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=regs-auth
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://regs-auth-ms
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/v1/auth/register
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[1]=Path=/api/v1/auth/authenticate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set any request that match /api/v1/auth/register "OR" /api/v1/auth/authenticate, you should set it as

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/v1/auth/register,/api/v1/auth/authenticate
```

And also you got 404 error due to path matching, path can not be /api/v1/auth/register "AND" /api/v1/auth/authenticate at the same time.